# Overriding Helper

Tags: magento-1.9, helper

I'm trying to override the Helper_Data of a thirdparty module. But for some reason it wont work.

> app/etc/modules/My_CustomModule.xml
>
> ```
> <?xml version="1.0"?>
> <config>
>     <modules>
>         <My_CustomModule>
>             <active>true</active>
>             <codePool>local</codePool>
>             <depends>
>                 <Idev_OneStepCheckout/>
>             </depends>
>         </My_CustomModule>
>     </modules>
> </config>
> ```

.

> app/code/local/My/CustomModule/etc/config.xml
>
> ```
> <?xml version="1.0"?>
> <config>
>     <modules>
>         <My_CustomModule>
>             <version>0.1.1</version>
>         </My_CustomModule>
>     </modules>
>     <global>
>         <helpers>
>             <onestepcheckout>
>                 <rewrite>
>                     <data>My_CustomModule_Helper_Data</data>
>                 </rewrite>
>             </onestepcheckout>
>         </helpers>
>     </global>
> </config>
> ```

.

> app/code/local/My/CustomModule/Helper/Data.php
>
> ```
> <?php
>     class My_CustomModule_Helper_Data extends Idev_OneStepCheckout_Helper_Data
>     {   
>         public function setCustomerComment($observer)
>         {
>           Mage::log(get_class($this), null, 'test.log');
>           // REST OF PARENT FUNCTION I WANT TO OVERRIDE
>         }
>     }
> ```

I already added a `Mage::log` to the function I'm trying to override but this keeps returning the classname of the original function.

**UPDATE:**

I did some digging in the code and found out that the function setCustomerComment is called by the observer event. I have no idea what this exactly does and or this just simply overrules the override?

> app/code/local/Idev/OneStepCheckout/etc/config.xml
>
> ```
> <?php    
>         <events>
>             <checkout_type_onepage_save_order>
>                 <observers>
>                     <onestepcheckout_save_customercomment>
>                         <type>model</type>
>                         <class>Idev_OneStepCheckout_Helper_Data</class>
>                         <method>setCustomerComment</method>
>                     </onestepcheckout_save_customercomment>
>                 </observers>
>             </checkout_type_onepage_save_order>
>             ...
>         </events>
> ```

I also created a file "test.php" in the root of magento with the code:

> test.php
>
> ```
> <?php
>
> include "app/Mage.php";
> Mage::app();
>
> $customerHelper = Mage::helper('onestepcheckout/data');
> var_dump(get_class($customerHelper));
> ```

This returns the module I have created, so it should override the initial class and functions right?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Did your custom module appears as "Enable" in your BO (system > configuration> Advanced > Advanced) ?

Comment: Yes it does, the module is active.

Comment: Do you flush the cache ? How do you call you setCustomerComment function in your code ?

Comment: Also flushed the cache. The function is run after the order is placed in magento (frontend).

Comment: @Kozame please check my above question, i've added some research regarding your question:
> How do you call you setCustomerComment function in your code ?

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example if you want to override **Mage_Checkout_Helper_Data**

> app/etc/modules/My_Custommodule.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
  <modules>
    <My_Custommodule>
      <active>true</active>
      <codePool>local</codePool>
      <version>0.1.0</version>
    </My_Custommodule>
  </modules>
</config>
```

> app/code/local/My/Custommodule/etc/config.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
  <modules>
    <My_Custommodule>
      <version>0.1.0</version>
    </My_Custommodule>
  </modules>
  <global>
    <helpers>
        <custommodule>
          <class>My_Custommodule_Helper</class>
        </custommodule>
        <checkout>
                <rewrite>
                    <data>My_Custommodule_Helper_Checkout_Data</data>
          </rewrite>
        </checkout>
    </helpers>
  </global>
</config>
```

> app/code/local/My/Custommodule/Helper/Data/Data.php

```
<?php
class My_Custommodule_Helper_Data extends Mage_Core_Helper_Abstract
{

}
```

> app/code/local/My/Custommodule/Helper/Checkout/Data.php

```
<?php
class My_Custommodule_Helper_Checkout_Data extends Mage_Checkout_Helper_Data
{

}
```

> app/code/local/My/Custommodule/Helper/Checkout/Data.php overriding **Mage_Checkout_Helper_Data**

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but this does not explain what i'm doing wrong.

Comment: does it make any difference if i have "Module" in the module name My_CustomModule in uppercase? or should it be (like your example) in lowercase?

Comment: yes, some time it create issues I would prefer **My_Custommodule** instead of **My_CustomModule**

Comment: @Myron : you can check with https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11547151/is-it-possible-to-use-camelcase-class-names-in-magento-models

Answer (score 0):

Declaration of your helper class is wrong. please check below code.

> app/code/local/My/CustomModule/etc/config.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <My_CustomModule>
            <version>0.1.1</version>
        </My_CustomModule>
    </modules>
    <global>
        <helpers>
            <custommodule> <!-- change here -->
                <class>My_CustomModule_Helper</class>
            </custommodule> <!-- change here -->
            <onestepcheckout>
                <rewrite>
                    <data>My_CustomModule_Helper_Data</data>
                </rewrite>
            </onestepcheckout>
        </helpers>
    </global>
</config>
```

Comment: This didn't do the trick unfortunately. Thanks for the response.